# PHP: How to add badge to Google Firebase payload?

Tags: php, android

I'm using Google Firebase to send push notifications to Android devices..

I'm using a PHP payload which works absolutely fine.

However, I need to know if there is a way of adding a Badge to the notification. By badge i mean that round circle thing that appears on the top of the app icon when it receives a push note.

My PHP payload is like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{ \"notification\": {\"title\": \"APP NAME\", \"sound\": \"default\",   \"text\": \"".$message."\"  },    \"to\" : \"". $deviceID."\"}");
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out [this docs](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#badges) to see how they send badge data. IT should work for you as well

Comment: @abeyaz, is `notId` for showing the badge?

Comment: No, it is to give a unique id to the message. See the `badge` parameter.

Comment: @abeyaz, thats the thing... the badge : 1 works for iOS but it doesn't work for android.

Comment: As far as i know, not all devices/android versions support it. If you are sure that your device supports it, try to use `data` instead of `notification` in the payload as shown in the page i shared.

Comment: @abeyaz, ahhh, that answers it mate... my Android doesn't support it i think.. never seen any other apps with badgeon this device.... Thanks for the info..

Comment: You can still test by using an android 6-7 emulator i guess.